# objective c meta class understanding and practice using

Tags: ios, objective-c, metaclass, objective-c-runtime

I have found this [link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html) that describe what is a meta-class. As I understood this is a part of my object. So I have data structure for example Car with some addres in memory wich include also isa pointer that is also some object with address in runtime and isa objec also has a class wich is also an object in the memory and it points to nsobject? Is this meta class? What I can do with using this knowledges?